# Javascript count down timer based on hours (works in Unbounce)

Tags: javascript

I need the javascript countdown timer to work based on the hours. For E.g. If it is 5'o clock then clock should reset from one hour. When it's 6'o clock it should again reset and count down should start.

Like in this website -> https://phorge.com.au/the-dental-edge-webinar

I would like to use following JS. So it would be great if it could be modified.

```
<script>
var startTime = 59.99; //in Minutes
var doneClass = "done"; //optional styling applied to text when timer is done

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  var intervalLoop = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      document.querySelector("#timer").classList.add(doneClass);
      clearInterval(intervalLoop);
     }
   }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  var setMinutes = 60 * startTime,
  display = document.querySelector("#timer");
  startTimer(setMinutes, display);
};
/**
    * Do not remove this section; it allows our team to troubleshoot and track feature adoption. 
    * TS:0002-03-069
*/
</script>
```

Comment: @SPlatten No it's correct, he's declaring 3 variables and assigning a value to the first one.

Comment: @chsdk i am using unbounce. This code works with minutes. But starts from beginning when page refreshes. I want it to take values from system hours or function getHours() and works based on it.

Comment: You can check the answer below, I think it gives you the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Just get the current time and subtract the minutes and seconds from your `startTime`. As it's a countdown timer per hour you don't care *what* hour it is, just how many minutes and seconds are left in it.

```js
var startTime = 59.99; //in Minutes
var doneClass = "done"; //optional styling applied to text when timer is done

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  var intervalLoop = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      document.querySelector("#timer").classList.add(doneClass);
      clearInterval(intervalLoop);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();

  if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 11 + " PM"
  } else {
    hour = hour + 1 + " AM"
  }

  document.getElementById("hour").textContent = "Until " + hour;

  var setMinutes = 60 * (startTime - now.getMinutes() - (now.getSeconds() / 100)),
    display = document.querySelector("#timer");

  startTimer(setMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span><br/>
<span id="hour"></span>
```

Comment: you actually get it and it works now. Thank you so much for this. Can you please do me a favor to include Hour in it?
So when it is 7 PM for a second it will stay as 01 and then should change to 00?

Comment: @SahibjotSingh for that just change the `startTime` to `60` I guess.

Comment: Don't we need another variable or something to take value for Hour? It displays correct time left for completion of an hour, but just shows minutes and seconds.

Comment: unfortunately that stopped working. The edit doesn't work and stopped the previous counter. :(
Just need to include hours so it should display like 

  00      00          00

Don't need PM or AM

Comment: don't we need to add something here
`code
var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  var intervalLoop = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      document.querySelector("#timer").classList.add(doneClass);
      clearInterval(intervalLoop);`
sorry i am not really good with it but just have some understanding.